# Can't start mysql server in xubuntu

Tags: mysql, xampp, xubuntu

Hey all i am using Xampp version 1.7.1 in xubuntu 10.10. 
I have installed it in /opt/lampp but problem is that whenever i try to start the server using `sudo ./lampp start`

it shows:

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
Warning: World-writable config file '/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

So what should i do??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first check the permissions of the file my.cnf, by running `ls -la /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`.

You will see something like

```
 -rwxrw-rw- 1 root root 4998 Oct 28 2010 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf
```

You can then change the permissions of the file, by typing `sudo chmod 644 /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`

Try to run `ls -la /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`, to see if it has changed permissions.

Comment: thanks for this solution really helpful solved my problem